# SUM cells that are 4 cells RIGHT of a specific date

Tags: excel-formula

I have a ledger and I want to SUM the cells that are 4 cells RIGHT of any specific date.

For example I want to SUM all the numbers in all cells 4 spaces RIGHT of the 01-Feb-19

[image]

Many thanks,
Colm

Comment: I think you should identify a better way of structuring your data.  If this very simple requirement is already becoming difficult to achieve, you're never going to be able to anything more sophisticated.  Suggest you look into how to use 'SUMIF' as it will do what you want, but I think you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @JeffUK is 100% right. Check [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b). It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple SUMIF will do it:

```
=SUMIF(A:M,"01-Feb-19",E:Q)
```

The key is the offset same size ranges.

Comment: Thanks Scott / Jeff, this only works for items on 1st of each month. I'm trying to get the sum for anything in a month but even when I change the criteria to "Feb-19" is still ignores any other dates than the 1st of Feb

Answer (score 0):

Also you can you:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$29,A2:E23,5,FALSE),0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$29,G2:K28,5,FALSE),0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$29,M2:Q26,5,FALSE),0)
```

at B29 import the date you want to sum (see image)

[image]